# How can I query the object with the latest date from an array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I've been trying and googling this for long and never arrived to any port.

If I have a collection that looks like this

```json
[
{
    "_id": "61394b1dbccf101ef4f57517",  # It's an object Id
    "name": "name-A",
    "throws": [
        {
            "date": "2021-08-11T00:00:00.000Z",
            "numberA": 3333,
            "numberB": 1241,
            "numberC": 1234,
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-08-16T00:00:00.000Z",
            "numberA": 6744,
            "numberB": 8656,
            "numberC": 2345,
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
            "numberA": 1234,
            "numberB": 5432,
            "numberC": 7556,
        },
    ],
},
{
    # Another document (aka object)
},
{
    # Another document (aka object)
},
...
]
```

I want to query the collection so that.... Given an ObjectId, Mongo returns the latest item of the array called "throws" based on its date attribute, for the document with the given id. Note that dates may or may not be ordered. I'll give the example of the expected output given the collection I've described and {id:"61394b1dbccf101ef4f57517"}:

```json
{
    "date": "2021-08-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    "numberA": 6744,
    "numberB": 8656,
    "numberC": 2345,
}
```

Both the solution for raw mongo-cli and the one for js-mongoose could help me.. But if you can explain me how this works in raw mongo it would be better for my learning i guess...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First `$match` by your desired `_id`.
- Then `$unwind` to deconstructs the array.
- Use this `$set` stage only if your data is an string and not an `ISODate`. If data is Date you don't need this step. This is to create `ISODate` objects to sort.
- Also use `$sort`.
- And then `$gorup` giving the `$first` value. As `$sort` is used, first value will be desired value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "61394b1dbccf101ef4f57517"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$throws"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "throws.date": {
        "$toDate": "$throws.date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "throws.date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      "throws": {
        "$first": "$throws"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L7thdPcftxa)

Comment: Ok, that's not EXACTLY what I was looking for, but it is a VVVVERY good one... I'll try to do that in my code and then I'll back to tell the results